# Node.js server receive 2 requests

Tags: node.js, curl

I have node.js server side:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.url);
}).listen(10001);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

And I try to connect to this server from PHP, using curl like that:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://'.$address);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data,true));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Why I get 2 requests to server (console showing url "/") when i making only 1?
I trying to make chat using socket.io and need to do some actions from PHP.

Comment: Your server never responds to incoming requests.  My guess is curl times out and retries.

Comment: I already tried with respond (this is example, real code is larger, but with same problem). These requests income almost at the same time (not after 1 or 2 seconds).